# After creating an LDA model from documents, how do I assign topics?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, lda

I have run some gensim code to create an LDA model from a set of documents.  From there it has created a list of 10 topics.  Is it possible to then go back to all of those documents, and assign them to one of those 10 topics (or none if applicable)?

I have not been able to find any code samples to accomplish this online.

Thank you